# what process do I attach to for a console app?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

When I want to debug a .net console application, what process do I attach to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You attach to the application process itself. A console application is no different from a winforms or wpf application in that sense.

Answer (score 2):

You should attach to the name of the process you want to debug.  Typically this is the same name as the name of the project when opened in Visual Studio.